# Java howto paint on a graphic in an order I want

Tags: java, graphics, arraylist

In C# I saw already the SpriteBatch class **(In the XNA plugin for XBOX games)**. In that class is it posible to paint in layers.
Now I want to do the same in Java because I'm making braid (See my other questions) and I have an ArrayList from all  the GameObjects and that list is not made in the correct paintoreder.

For exemple: I have a door but the door is painted on the player.

Martijn

Comment: Can you be a little more specific? What API are you using to do the drawing?

Comment: Why is this question tagged "C++"?

Comment: sorry this was a mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about sorting the items before rendering?
The background items have to be painted first and the foreground ones last.

If you have a List and items are Comparable you can use

```
Collections.sort(list);
```

If you need a special order, you can implement your own Comparator.

All that of course requires the items to hold some info on their z-position.

And you shouldn't do this in the paint method. sort items when they're changed, ie. added.

Comment: thanks I will try it and let you know something. It looks a great solution

Answer (score 2):

Sorting the list of items should solve your issue, but if you do find you need to paint layers, you can do it like this:

Create a BufferedImage for each layer

```
    BufferedImage[] bi = new BufferedImage[3];
    bi[0] = new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
```

Paint into the buffered images

```
    Graphics2D bg2 = bi[0].createGraphics();
    bg2.drawXXX(...);
```

That should all be outside the actual paint method.

In the paint or paintComponent method, use alpha compositing to assemble the layers

```
    AlphaComposite ac = AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, 1.0f);
    g2.setComposite(ac);
    for (int i = 0; i < bi.length; i++) {
        g2.drawImage(b[i], 0, 0, this);
    }
```